# If $x=2\cos t-\cos 2t $, $y=2\sin t -\sin 2t$, find the value of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ when $t= \pi /2$

Tags: calculus

**Question  $\boldsymbol 7$.** If $x=2\cos t-\cos 2t $, $y=2\sin t -\sin 2t$, find the value of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ when $t= \pi /2$

**Solution:**

\begin{align*}
y &= 2\sin t -\sin 2t \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= 2\cos t -2\cos 2t \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &=-2\sin t +2\sin 2t \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} =\frac{\cos t-\cos 2t}{-\sin t +\sin 2t} \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\cos t-\cos 2t}{-\sin t +\sin 2t}\right) \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&=\frac{(\sin 2t -\sin t) \frac{d}{dt}(\cos t -\cos 2t) -(\cos t -\cos 2t) \frac{d}{dt}(\sin 2t -\sin t)}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&=\frac{(\sin 2t -\sin t) (-\sin t -2\sin 2t) -(\cos t -\cos 2t) (2\cos 2t -\cos t)}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{(\sin t -\sin 2t) (\sin t +2\sin 2t) +(\cos 2t -\cos t) (2\cos 2t -\cos t)}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{\sin^2 t +2\sin t \sin 2t -\sin t \sin 2t -2\sin^2 2t +\ldots  \\ \ldots +2\cos^2 2t -\cos t \cos 2t -2\cos t \cos 2t +\cos^2 t}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{1 +2(\cos^2 2t -\sin^2 2t) +\sin t \sin 2t -3\cos t \cos 2t}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}
\end{align*}

Have I done any mistake so far?

Comment: Please use MathJax to type your problem. Don't give us the hand-written solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt} (\cos t -\cos 2t) =-\sin t \color{red}{\boldsymbol +}2\sin 2t$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} 
&=\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\cos t-\cos 2t}{-\sin t +\sin 2t}\right) \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&=\frac{(\sin 2t -\sin t) \frac{d}{dt}(\cos t -\cos 2t) -(\cos t -\cos 2t) \frac{d}{dt}(\sin 2t -\sin t)}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&=\frac{(\sin 2t -\sin t) (-\sin t \color{red}{\boldsymbol +}2\sin 2t) -(\cos t -\cos 2t) (2\cos 2t -\cos t)}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{(\sin t -\sin 2t) (\sin t \color{red}{\boldsymbol -}2\sin 2t) +(\cos 2t -\cos t) (2\cos 2t -\cos t)}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{\sin^2 t \color{red}{\boldsymbol -}2\sin t \sin 2t -\sin t \sin 2t \color{red}{\boldsymbol +}2\sin^2 2t +\ldots  \\ \ldots +2\cos^2 2t -\cos t \cos 2t -2\cos t \cos 2t +\cos^2 t}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{1 +2(\cos^2 2t \color{red}{\boldsymbol +}\sin^2 2t) \color{red}{\boldsymbol{-3}}\sin t \sin 2t -3\cos t \cos 2t}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{3 -3}}\sin t \sin 2t -3\cos t \cos 2t}{(\sin 2t -\sin t)^2} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \ldots
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for specifically pointing out my mistake. Though I would equally thank Key Flex for editing the question. Since I have to mark just one answer as the correct answer I would like to mark Rocherz's answer as the correct one as I really wanted to know what mistake I had done. I am thankful to others as well for contributing to the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

$$x = 2\cos t -\cos 2t$$

$$y = 2\sin t -\sin 2t$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -2\sin t +2\sin 2t$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 2\cos t -2\cos 2t$$

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{(+\sin 2t-\sin t)(-\sin t+2\sin 2t)-(-\cos 2t+\cos t)(-\cos t+2\cos 2t)}{(-\sin t+\sin 2t)^2}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}_{[\frac{\pi}{2}]} = -\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: The answer in the book  is $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: It seem its (1,2) of cardioid, and it is negative value.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D2cost-cos2t,+y%3D2sint-sin2t,

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Yes, you are right. The answer is $\frac{-3}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{2\cos t-2\cos2t}{-2\sin t+2\sin2t}=\dfrac{\cos2t-\cos t}{\sin t-\sin2t}$$
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{(-2\sin2t+\sin t)(\sin t-\sin2t)-(\cos2t-\cos t)(\cos t-2\cos2t)}{(\sin t-\sin2t)^2-2(\sin t-\sin2t)}$$

Now $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\bigg|_{t=\frac{\pi}{2}}=\dfrac{(1)(1-0)-(-1-0)(0-2(-1))}{-2(1-0)^3}=-\dfrac32$$

Comment: could you tell me if there is conceptually anything wrong and I cannot find anything wrong unless you tell me if something is basically wrong

Comment: @SatishRamanathan I didn't find anything wrong with your solution. But, I wonder how this question is yielding to two different answers.

Comment: You are right in your answer.  I made a mistake. I am upvoting yours.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{y'_t}{x'_t}$$
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\left(\frac{y'_t}{x'_t}\right)'_t}{x'_t}=
\frac{x'_ty''_{tt}-x''_{tt}y'_t}{(x'_t)^3}$$

I get

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\bigg|_{t=\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1; y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2;\\
x=2\cos t-\cos 2t \Rightarrow \cos^2t-2\cos t+x-1=0 \Rightarrow \cos t=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{3-2x}}2;\\
x^2+y^2=5-4\cos t=5-2+2\sqrt{3-2x};\\
2x+2yy'=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3-2x}} \Rightarrow y'(1)=-1;\\
2+2y'^2+2yy''=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{(3-2x)^2}} \Rightarrow y''(1)=\frac{-6}4=-\frac32.$$